# Visual Studio 2013 and Chart Control for .net 3.5

Tags: vb.net, .net-3.5, visual-studio-2013

Good afternoon!

So I have developed an application through Visual Studio 2013 using vb.net. It contains the default MS chart control and fills it with data from my database. My application runs beautifully on my Windows 7 .net 4.5 environment. No problems there.

Now that it's time to publish, I remember that my app needs to run in .net 3.5 for Windows XP users. So, I converted the project to .net 3.5 framework. Apparently, my chart control only works for .net 4.0 and up, giving me all kinds of errors. So, I publish the app regardless of the errors with the wizard and run it on my Windows 7 PC. It works! Now, I try to run the application in my Windows XP virtual machine with .net 3.5. (I have installed the Microsoft .net 3.5 chart control to XP in hopes that it will end up working.)

This is the error I'm getting when I run the application on my XP: "Cannot continue. The application is improperly formatted. Contact the application vendor for assistance."

I'm still relatively new to publishing, so I'm not sure exactly what is wrong here. Is there a problem with the chart control, or is something wrong with the published files?

I have considered converting the app to .net 4.0, but the users that need the app are still running in 3.5.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You published it with all kinds of errors and expect it to work?

Comment: Yep! Funny thing is that it actually did for my Windows 7 PC. The errors are from .net 3.5 not recognizing the chart control.

Comment: can you not download framework v4 for xp and get your users to install?

Comment: I considered it. Since it's for a business and there are several users, I'm trying to keep it as user-friendly as I can. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I have it working now. I ended up installing VS 2010 on my Windows XP virtual machine and recreating the app there, copy/pasting code. With that, I was able to use the .NET 3.5 chart control without any issues. The publish and installation were both successful.

It looked like using an older version of VS was my best option. I thought it was best not to force users to install .NET 4.0.

Thank you guys for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the .NET 4.0 version of the Chart Control you will experience issues with running on .NET 3.5

It would be better to get hold of the .NET 3.5 version of the control and use that in a .NET 3.5 app.
In other words, Change your app to .NET 3.5, remove the existing MS Chart control and use the .NET 3.5 version.

Download: [Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That does help point me in the right direction, but the .net 3.5 control is not compatible with Windows 7... Argh!